# Form to open in new tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's two issues with this form:

1. The first form doesn't open in new tab when submitted although i have added target="_blank"
2. When the "LOGIN" button is clicked, until the newly open tab closes or loads completely, the current form freezes. I can't seem to figure out why!

HTML:

```
<form target="_blank" onsubmit="window.location = 'http://sub1.domain.com?tt=' + search.value; return false;">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1"> Tracking ID</label>  &nbsp; 
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2" > OPC</label>
<div id="Track1" class="desc" style="display: none;">
                <br />
                <input id="search" class="TrackInput" onclick="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='IYIUY'" type="text" placeholder="IYIUY" type="search" name="search">
                <br />
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Track</button>
</div>

<div id="Track2" class="desc" style="display: none;">
<a href="http://sub2.domain.com" target="_blank">LOGIN</a>
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='optradio']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Track" + test).show();
    });
});
```

Could someone put some thought as to why both the issues are happening?

[DEMO JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrc8gjzr/)

Answer (score 0):

You've added `return false` in your `onsubmit` `event` for `form`

```
onsubmit="window.location = 'http://sub1.domain.com?tt=' + search.value; return false;">
```

`return false` will prevent its default action. So just remove that `return false` at the end. Everything else looks good.

## [`Updated Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qrc8gjzr/2/)

Comment: Thank You. Doing that doesn't solve the problem though. When I remove "return false", it takes me to this link instead: http://domain.com/?optradio=1&search=43532

Comment: what's your domain name?? Did you change it?

Comment: No, I didn't change the domain name. I simply removed the "return false" so it looks like this: `<form target="_blank" onsubmit="window.location = 'http://sub1.domain.com?tt=' + search.value;">` and the resulting page has the sub-domain removed along with the search value :(

Comment: because I feel that this `sub1.domain.com` doesn't exist!! Does it??

Comment: Yes, it does. It works when i have `return false` added. It doesn't work when I remove it.

Comment: Ok.. What's your domain?? `sub1.domain.com`?

Comment: The domain where this code is placed is `domain.com` and the users would be using the form here. Once the user enters the data, it gets redirected to `sub1.domain.com`.